# Storing @discordjs/voice VoiceChannel in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord.js, voice

I'm trying to store a @discordjs/voice VoiceChannel object in a MongoDB database but doing so results in `Error: cyclic dependency detected`. So does anybody know a way todo this? Or if i can store the channel id and then get the voice channel? I haven't found any function in @discordjs/voice that allows for getting a voice channel from an ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind. I figured it out if you use `client.channels.fetch` on a voice channel it will actually return a VoiceChannel and not a Channel like the documentation it says.